# Исключить из выборки повторяющиеся элементы

Tags: jquery

Предположим, у нас есть такая разметка:

```
<tr>
    <td>Слово</td>
    <td>Слово</td>
    <td>Один</td>
    <td>Два</td>
    <td>Один</td>
</tr>
```

Как при помощи JQuery исключить из общей выборки повторяющиеся элементы. То есть, в данном примере должно остаться только Слово, Один, Два.

Comment: Исключаются они не JQuery, а занесением в обычный ассоциативный массив.

Comment: А в JQuery, например, с помощью функции filter() или какой-то другой никак нельзя?

Comment: Как-то так (пишу вслепую, могу накосячить):

    var data = $( ":td" ).map(function() {return this.innerHTML;}).get();
    var unique = [];
    data.forEach(function(item,i) {unique[item] = item;});

Comment: Так вроде это обычное занесение в новый массив внутренностей каждого td. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: В массив unique будут только искомые "Слово", "Один", "Два".

Comment: В вашем примере data возвращается в виде пустого массива.

Comment: предупреждал же:

>пишу вслепую, могу накосячить

неважно как получать данные, вся суть в последней строке. btw, переносить пример 1:1 не надо, пропишите свои данные (селектор, класс, объект или что там у вас)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно отфильтровать элементы в доме, просто получаем список в массив фильтруем и заменяем.
http://jsfiddle.net/5BSqB/

```
var elems = ["Слово", "Слово", "Один", "Два", "Один"],
        res = [],
        index;// переменную вынес что бы она каждый раз не иницилиазировалась в функции

    elems.forEach(function (item, i) {
        index = res.indexOf(item);// ищем элемент в новом массиве

        if(!~index) // если его нет 
           res.push(item)//добавляем 
    });

    $("#items").html("<td>"+ res.join("</td><td>") + "</td>");
```

Comment: Спасибо. А можно парочку комментариев в цикл forEach добавить, не до конца понятны действия.

Comment: Спасибо. Меня просто ввела в ступор вот эта строка if(!~index) - тильда(~) - это же опечатка?

Comment: @andreyqin нет, по сути это условие аналогично условию if(index == -1), ~ производит побитовую операцию над каждым битом, заменяя его на обратный ему, т.е 10000000000001 станет 01111111111110 , вот почитайте http://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators

Comment: @cyber_ua, а обычное логичествое НЕ (!) тут не подойдет?

Comment: Подойдёт и `index == -1` - но, видимо, это недостаточно круто выглядит :)

Comment: @andreyqin "а обычное логичествое НЕ (!) тут не подойдет?" нет не подойдет так как -1 при приведенеие к булевому значению будет true.

Comment: Прекрасно работает `if(index {!=|==} -1)`, к булевскому приводится не -1, а результат выражения (точнее, он булевским и является)

Comment: @klopp, к чему эта дискуссия? я написал в первом ответе что это альтернативная запись if(index == -1) "по сути это условие аналогично условию if(index == -1)"

Comment: А вам не кажется странным - писать комментарий, получать на него ответ, потом стирать комментарий и удивляться: к чему это?

Comment: @klopp, а вам не кажется что у hashcode`а ограничение на кол-во комментариев к ответу? Попробуйте напишите 11 комменты. И я удалил только без полезные комменты.